# uilabel animating to original position

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel

I'm trying to animate a `UILabel` frame to a position in the middle of the screen. Instead, it seems to be animating from somewhere outside the view back to its original position.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"labelAnim" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.scoreLabel setFrame:self.endScoreFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here are the starting and ending frames:

```
Start Frame: {{10, 30}, {144, 21}}
Final Frame: {{93.75, 158.71438598632812}, {187.5, 46.875}}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint right before you start setting up your animation. At that point, what is the `UILabel`'s frame?

Comment: the start frame is this:(origin = (x = 10, y = 30), size = (width = 144, height = 21)) and the end frame is this:(origin = (x = 93.75, y = 158.71438598632813), size = (width = 187.5, height = 46.875))

Comment: Is that the expected start frame?

Comment: yes it is, and the end frame is correct too.

Comment: Strange. Does the label have any transforms applied to it prior to animation?

Comment: no, this is the only time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [self.scoreLabel setFrame:self.endScoreFrame];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSlog("completed");
                     }];
```

And make sure your `endScoreFrame` have the correct new position coordinates:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.endScoreFrame));
```

I have tested this code with the values of your old and new frames and it works fine:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lbl;
```

*ViewDidLoad:*

```
self.lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 144, 21)];
self.lbl.text = @"mylabel";

[self.view addSubview:self.lbl] ;
```

*Action*

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender
{ 

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(93.75, 158.71438598632812, 187.5, 46.875);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         self.lbl.frame = newFrame ;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];

}
```

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same result with this code.

Comment: I have updated the code, and can you please NSLog the original frame and the end frame see my updated answer.

Comment: @Uon check my update you maybe missed something since the code above is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had forgotten that I had the label I was trying to animate in Interface Builder, so it was being overridden.